# TestNG - Cannot find class in classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, testng

I am doing Java-Eclipse-TestNG and having trouble running tests using testng command line. I've multiple source folders and when the .class files are created they are going to /bin directory with the same folder structure as /src as shown below. I've set the classpath (using export CLASSPATH=...) to all the folders in /bin directory and tried to run "java org.testng.TestNG testng.xml", but what it gives me is "Cannot find class in classpath: TestCases.TC_0001". My testng.xml file is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Default suite">
  <test verbose="2" name="Default test">
    <classes>
    <class name="TestCases.TC_0001">
    </class>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Default test -->
</suite> <!-- Default suite -->
```

[image: This is my folder structure]

Comment: Could you try with the `-cp` option of the `java` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you export the class path to bin/CIQLib/AIPClasses/;bin/CIQLib/BaseCLasses and so on.
Just pointing it to CIQLib will not help.
And here's the reason why:

> classpath1;classpath2 Class paths to the .jar, .zip or .class files.
>   Each classpath should end with a filename or directory depending on
>   what you are setting the class path to: For a .jar or .zip file that
>   contains .class files, the class path ends with the name of the .zip
>   or .jar file. For .class files in an unnamed package, the class path
>   ends with the directory that contains the .class files. **For .class
>   files in a named package, the class path ends with the directory that
>   contains the "root" package (the first package in the full package
>   name).**

Ref: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Comment: This is not the exact answer but this gave me a hint. Somewhere I read that I need to give "*" after the folder like "bin/CIQLib/AIPClasses/\*;". When I removed the *, it started working. Also, I had to separately give full path for the jar files. Both of these solved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Well a * works if there are multiple jar files in a folder that you want to put into the class path.. For classes you need to lead up to the folder that has the root package folder..